# Issue with running "Update-Database" Power Shell Command using C# code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying the latest Entity Framework Migrations beta 01 release. It works fine using Visual Studio Power Shell. But when I'm going to run the PS command "Update-Database" using C# code, it gives me the errors -

> "Missing Required Parameter 1 "AssemblyName" in code line "" " and
>   "System.Management.Automation.RemoteException"

Then I tried the PS command "`Update-Database "EntityFramework"`. Then it says,

> "Could not load file or Assembly"

I used `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline` class to invoke Power Shell command. Can some one help me.

Thank you.

Comment: This is the place that I learnt to use "Migrations" - [Code-Based Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I already answered your question offline, Lasantha, but for the benefit of everyone else on StackOverflow...

The PowerShell commands that we ship with Migrations are very specific to the NuGet/Visual Studio environment and will not work outside of it.

If you are interested in running Migrations from code, Rowan's [Running & Scripting Migrations from Code](http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/) post is a great resource for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Brice's link is a very good resource, it got me started as well and led to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14339379/219187

Just use `ScriptUpdate(null, null)` to update to the latest migration.